# Batch Copy 1 Random File from each sub folder and move to a folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am looking for a batch script that copies 1 random file per folder to a specified folder.

I have been using this, it looks for mp3 and copies them in random order to a specified folder. I would prefer to modify this script to take 1 file per folder and no more no less making sure there cannot be 2 files from the same folder copied.

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "musicroot=D:\files"
set "playfolder=F:\dump"
set /a filecount=351

pushd "%musicroot%"
for /r %%i in (*.mp3) do set /a files+=1& set "$!files!=%%~i"
popd
pushd "%playfolder%"
:randomloop
set /a rd=%random%%%files+1
set "mp3=!$%rd%!"
if not defined mp3 goto :randomloop
set "$%rd%="
for %%i in ("%mp3%") do if exist "%%~nxi" echo "%%~nxi" already exist in %playfolder%.& goto:randomloop
copy "%mp3%"
set /a filecount-=1
if %filecount% gtr 0 goto:randomloop
popd
```

Any ideas how it could perhaps be modified to do what i want? Sorry i'm not great at batch.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd \particular\folder
set n=0
for %%f in (*.*) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "file[!n!]=%%f"
)
set /A "rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1"
copy "!file[%rand%]!" \different\folder
```

This is for a particular folder (**Tested**). Loop it for multiple folders.

**Update 2.** The following code will *Copy 1 Random File from each sub folder and move to a folder*. (Did the looping part). **Tested and working**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd \particular\folder
set t=0
for /d %%i in (*) do (
    cd "%%i"
    set /A t+=1
    set n[!t!]=0
    for %%f in (*.*) do (
       set /A n[!t!]+=1
       set "file[!n!]=%%f"
    )
    set /A "rand=(n[!t!]*%random%)/32768+1"
    copy "!file[%rand%]!" D:\complete\destination
    cd..
)
pause
```

Comment: First one copies 1 file from specified root folder, the second one i can't get to copy anything, no errors though, ideas?

Comment: I couldn't test the second one. Maybe you could try to loop in `cd \particular\folder`  and find something as the first one works perfectly. And maybe there aren't any folders in "particular\folder" so you are not able to copy anything.

Comment: there's 3 folders in \particular\folder that has 100 random unique files each in them, not getting anything though, ill try to figure it out, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I'm getting The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified. 3 times when i run it now, i've renamed the folders to have no spaces as i though it might be the reason for the issue but still occurring, is there a syntax issue somewhere?

Comment: ya me too. Working on it. Trying to fix it,

Comment: hey!! I got It.. Posting soon. Mark my answer as correct for others to follow.

Comment: works! now to figure out what you changed to make it work :) Thanks a lot for help help!

Comment: Actually it works, but it doesn't seem to randomize the pick out of each folder, instead it picks whatever file is "last in order" based on "date created"

Comment: No, that's just because of the random function of the windows command line. It got assigned to the very value for the same time as it does not have any randomize function. Simply, the results would be different on different days or each time the code is edited or the computer reboots.

Comment: After using this script for a couple of weeks it's clear to me it's not picking files up at random, it's ALWAYS picking the last file by date in each folder, every single time, no matter if i reboot computer or not it always picks the last so the code: rand=(n[!t!]*%random%)/32768+1 isn't randomizing anything, it's just taking the last file in each folder based on date created.